# Создать многоуровневое меню через php и mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Есть две таблицы

Категории и подкатегории.

Как правильно вывести категории с нужными подкатегориями. Связь между таблицами по id категорий.

Хочится понять алогоритм, как люди реализовывают такое меню через базу?

Comment: А зачем вам 2 таблицы для этого? Будет достаточно одной таблицы с полями id, parent_id, name. Получаете эти значения и записываете их в многомерный массив, далее работаете с этим массивом.

Comment: а что будет в parent_id

Comment: Ссылка на id родительской категории в этой таблицы.

Comment: ну вот значит нужна вторая таблица

Comment: Я же написал "в этой таблице". Пример:

    id | parent_id | name
    1  | null      | Новости
    2  | 1         | Политика
    3  | 1         | Экономика

Comment: @duddeniska, вы зря так уверены. @andreyqin дело говорит.

Comment: А вот так вот! Хм прикольно! А как правильно работать с массивом? мне бы просто алгоритм а не код!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> А вот так вот! Хм прикольно! А как
> правильно работать с массивом? мне бы
> просто алгоритм а не код!

ну смотрите, если использовать структуру, которую предложил  [@andreyqin](/users/12995/andreyqin) , то можно брать из базы все поля и сортировать по parent_id.  Тем самым вы полчите данные типо

```
id | parent_id | name
1  | 1        | Новости
2  | 1        | Политика
3  | 2        | Экономика
```

И сможете бежать по этому массиву и уже генерить представления для них.

Как вариант, можно результат из базы группировать по нужным критериям и получать уже на выходе ассоциативный массив данных.